# Refining key-chord.el triggering

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts, elisp

I do *really* like `key-chord.el` but I'd need it to only trigger when I start pressing keystrokes *after* a short delay during which I didn't do anything elapsed.  I'd like to know if it's easy to modify `key-chord.el` to do that.

Why I want that is simple and I'll try to explain it as easily as I can:

- I do want keychords to be assigned to keys that are on my "strong" fingers (no pinky) and that are on my home row (I do touch-type).  Hence I'm potentially creating quite a few keychords which may clash with common words / code when I'm typing.
- I realized that everytime there's a clash (i.e. keychords kicking in while I didn't want to) it's because I'm in the process of frenziedly modifying the buffer.

Here's an example...

I'm a fast typist so if I'm entering, say, "held", there is **never** going to be a long delay between when I add the 'e' of "held" and when I then type the 'l'.  So in this case it should be "obvious" that I do not want key-chord to kick in when I type 'ld'.  However if there's a pause and **if** 'ld' is an assigned key-chord and then I hit 'ld', then it is **very** unlikely that I'm writing code / text that would be starting with 'ld'.  So in this later case (and because I have assigned 'ld' to a key-chord), I do want it to kick in.

Now don't get me wrong: I'm *not* sayin this would eliminate every single possible clash in every single case.  All I'm saying is that, in my case, this would probably eliminate 99.9% of the (already rare) clashes.  The "time lost" should one clash still occur after this change to key-chord would be negligible compared to the amount of time key-chord is making me gain.

The code to `key-chord.el` is very small so maybe such an addition wouldn't be too hard?

Does anyone have an idea as to how if it would be easy to modify `key-chord.el` to provide such a feature? (I hope I explained correctly what I want to do)

Here's the code to key-chord.el and half of it is comments:

http://emacswiki.org/emacs/key-chord.el

Comment: note that I'd like to at least try it, to see if this idea makes sense or not...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Idle Timer mechanism should be able to facilitate this.

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp) Idle Timers` <kbd>RET</kbd>

I'll leave it to you (or someone else) to figure out the details. Offhand thoughts are:

- enable the Key Chord functionality via an idle timer
- use `post-command-hook` to disable it again

That *might* be all that is needed?

Answer (score 2):

I see two timings at play here

- time before the chord (between the letter before the chord and the chord. If short enough, no chord)
- time after the chord (if new letter quickly typed, no chord)

The **second type** of timing is probably more natural, and easy to get used to. If one type the chord, a short timeout before it executes can be accepted. (This is not what you asked for and would not solve the "ld" example. But it could potentially solve the problem with letter combinations that may appear in the beginning of words.)

The **first type** of timing is probably harder to get used to. When one have completed typing a word and the next thing is to type a chord, I suspect it is not a natural instinct to make a short pause. If one uses the chord often, one is likely to type it quickly, and get annoyed if it is not recognized (and the two chars are inserted into the text instead). What I want to say is, **I am not sure a timing before the chord will solve the problem to a satisfactory degree**.

As for the implementation of such a timing. The way the state machine in the key-chord-input-method function is currently structured, it would grow exponentially with the number of timers to consider (if I recall correctly). I.e. there would be at least about a dozen new lines of code.

To experiment with the functionality, try **phils** suggestion in the other answer: a post command that disables chords, and an idle timer that, after a fraction of a second, enables them again. A quick and dirty way to disable and enable chords, without actually changing minor mode, would be to set the input-method-function variable.

**Code for test purpose only**. It assumes, but does not check, that key-chord-mode version 0.5 is loaded and enabled:

```
;; Helper functions to be used in timers and hooks
(defun my-enable-chords () (setq input-method-function 'key-chord-input-method))
(defun my-disable-chords () (setq input-method-function nil))

;; Start test
(add-hook 'post-command-hook 'my-disable-chords)
(setq my-timer (run-with-idle-timer 0.3 'repeat 'my-enable-chords))

;; Finish test
(remove-hook 'post-command-hook 'my-disable-chords)
(cancel-timer my-timer)
```